# HTML (only), Image appears when hovering mouse over text

Tags: html, image, hover

can anyone tell me if it is possible to make an image appear when you hover the mouse over a text?
I'm doing a school project and I can only use html, I've seen a lot of answers but most require CSS or jQuery and other languages.
Thanks

Comment: You might be able to use CSS, but it's typically done with JavaScript

Comment: I don't believe their is an only HTML solution for what you want. To not want jQuery and such makes sense; however, not wanting to use CSS really doesn't sound reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

HTML was not designed for that purpose, it was meant to give a website *basic structure*. It is really only used to organize and emphasis (and even that last one is mainly done from css or js) the text of a website.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I will try using css

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809922/in-html-how-can-you-make-an-image-appear-while-you-are-hovering-over-text). The solution isn't solely HTML, but it's pretty much impossible to do what you want only using that.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try, thanks