# Display an image while hover on a text

Tags: html, css

I tried to display a picture when you hover on a span-tag. I looked it up on the internet, but what I found didn't work. I now ended up with this code:

```
<span style="display:inline-block;">
 <img class="manImg" src="_src/mypicture.jpg">
</span>
```

...and the question is where to put the 'hoverable' text. When I hover on that text it will show the image.

Comment: `title` attribute?

Comment: Unfortunately not. If I do that I have a picture that shows me the text when I hover over it.

Comment: So what do you want instead?

Comment: That I have a text that shows a picture when I hover over it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make image appear on link hover css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270594/make-image-appear-on-link-hover-css)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In HTML, how can you make an image appear while you are hovering over text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27809922/in-html-how-can-you-make-an-image-appear-while-you-are-hovering-over-text)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
img { display: none; }    
.parent:hover img { display: block; }
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/t7ezpL30/1/)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by **css** only.

```
<span class="container">
  <p class="hover-text">Hover text here</p>
 <img class="manImg" src="_src/mypicture.jpg">
</span>

.container {
  display: inline-block;
}
.manImg {
  display: none;
}
.hover-text:hover ~ .manImg {
  display: block;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using JavaScript on onmouseover event.

```
<span style="display:inline-block;" onmouseover="your javascript code">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can do it:

```js
function mouseIn() {
  $('.img').addClass('show');
}

function mouseOut() {
  $('.img').removeClass('show');
}

$('.hover-me').hover(mouseIn, mouseOut);
```

```css
.img  {
  display: none;
}

.img.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="display:inline-block;">
  <p class="hover-me">hi</p>

 <img src="http://static.ddmcdn.com/en-us/apl/breedselector/images/breed-selector/dogs/breeds/australian-shepherd_01_sm.jpg" class="img">
</span>
```

This takes advantage of JQuery's `hover`. The image is hidden by default. When your mouse hovers over the text, I add a class to show the image. When your mouse stops hovering, I remove the class to hide the image again.