# add a hover effect over an image (better practices) CSS

Tags: html, css

I have 2 images:

[image]

I would like that when the cursor is above the image, it appears on the image, something like the image I attached:

[image]

What is the best way to achieve it? Can be achieved with :before?

https://jsfiddle.net/149p9wnm/

```
div.image1 {
 position:relative;
 background: url('http://kingofwallpapers.com/imagem/imagem-005.jpg') no-
 repeat scroll left top transparent;
 width: 232px;
 height: 200px;
}

div.image2 {
 position:relative;
 background: url('http://kingofwallpapers.com/imagem/imagem-006.jpg') no-
 repeat scroll left top transparent;
 width: 232px;
 height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Please show an attempt. You *almost* there. To ask a good question, you should show your attempts and why they have not worked. Right now it looks like you have put no effort into this and you want us to solve the problem. Show us that you have researched it and then where you have run into a block.

Comment: As titled with "better practices" I hope that you show your try with more than one solution and expose the pros and cons for both .... but you have zero tries .

Comment: try to put in those img name/description for each image (but set disaply: none as default so you are hidden them first), then add css hover for img to display those content(name/description)

Comment: @amflare ok, wait me..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display an image while hover on a text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42516712/display-an-image-while-hover-on-a-text)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    <div class="yourclass">

    <p>Your text</p>

    <img src="yourimage" alt="">
   </div>


    .yourclass{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    .yourclass:hover p{
    display: block;
}
    img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute; 
    }
    p{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I'll put you as the best answer, but I want to know how this works by having 2 or more items.

Comment: What do you mean 2 or more items? Like two different <p> tags?

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Answer (score -2):

```
<style>
.overlay {
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
bottom: 10px;
left: 10px;
right: 10px;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
opacity: 0;
background-color: black;
}
.div.image1:hover .overlay {
opacity: 0.8;
}
.text {
color: white;
font-size: 20px;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
</style>
<div class="overlay">
<div class="text">hey</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.